# Javascript How Can Change HTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have this HTML item.

```
<div class="inner" id="durum260" style="display: block;"><img src="/Content/plugins/images/teslim_edildi.png"></div>
```

This functions are works.

```
$('#durum260').hide();
$('#durum260').show();
```

How can I change bottom code with JS?

```
<img src="/Content/plugins/images/teslim_edildi.png"></div>
```

to

```
<img src="/Content/plugins/images/new_image.png"></div>
```

Comment: Have you attempted any research? Have you read through the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('drum260').firstChild.src = "/Content/plugins/images/new_image.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const img = document.querySelector('#durum260 > img');
img.src = img.src.replace('teslim_edildi', 'new_image');
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answers have correctly specified methods of altering the `src` attribute of the image in your specific code sample, I would suggest adding an `id` attribute to the image element and targeting it using `document.getElementById()`.

This will protect you in the event that your DOM tree changes. For example, if you add another image to the `<div>`, the image you want to change the `src` attribute on may no longer be the first image, so you would end up changing the `src` on the wrong one.

Similarly, if you add any other HTML element to the `<div>` before your image, it would no longer be the first child.